# Is it possible to share multiple files at once with the React Native Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

Is this possible?
Looked at the iOS version of the Facebook SDK and there's `FBSDKShareMediaContent` which takes an array of `FBSDKSharePhoto`, `FBSDKShareVideo` etc. but I couldn't find the equivalent in React Native's SDK for it. Am I missing some obvious and powerful abstraction or is this just plain missing?